# How to upgrade to WhatsApp's new stable native UWP version?

Tags: whatsapp, uwp

https://www.whatsapp.com/download/ removed the regular Windows version and kept only the UWP version, but [news everywhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=whatsapp%20uwp&gl=us&hl=en&biw=1920&bih=927&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A8%2F10%2F2022%2Ccd_max%3A8%2F31%2F2022&tbm=) claims even the UWP wasn't native before, and now it is.

Is the latest version 2.2228.14? If so, how to make sure it's native now?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Just wanting to enjoy the new benefits such as a "faster work, notifications arrive instantly and you don't need the program running in the background either."

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly my (UWP) WhatsApp closed itself without any alert, and when I re-opened it then it asked for a new QR scan even though the phone showed it's still connected to the computer.

Upon finally opening I saw it's version **2.2237.5.0** and it looks completely different than before (e.g. it's smaller and doesn't have a green bar at top). So I guess that's the first version that's native. It was probably a gradual upgrade that was rolled over for months.